# How to use margins in calculations?

Tags: beamer, calculations, dimensions

I'd like to have a rule that has for example the width of `\paperwidth-\leftmargin-\rightmargin`. I tried to use `\dimexpr`, but apparently I do something wrong, because it does not work.

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

%\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=250mm,paperheight=190.5mm,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm} 
\setbeamersize{text margin left=10mm,text margin right=60mm}

  \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \rule{\dimexpr\paperwidth-\leftmargin-\rightmargin\relax}{50mm}% 180mm = 250mm - 10mm - 60mm
    \end{frame}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The lengths you are looking for are stored in macros `\Gm@lmargin` (distance between left margin of paper and left border of text area) and `\Gm@rmargin` (distance between right border of text area and right margin of paper), so `\paperwidth=\Gm@lmargin+\textwidth+\Gm@rmargin`. Since the `\Gm@...` are macros, you can define some lengths first to easily use them in `\dimexpr` (see remark at the end):

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=250mm,paperheight=190.5mm,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm,bottom=0mm} 
\setbeamersize{text margin left=10mm,text margin right=60mm}

\makeatletter
\newlength\beamerleftmargin
\newlength\beamerrightmargin
\setlength\beamerleftmargin{\Gm@lmargin}
\setlength\beamerrightmargin{\Gm@rmargin}
\makeatother   

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\textcolor{blue}{\rule{\textwidth}{3pt}}

\textcolor{red}{\rule{\dimexpr\paperwidth-\beamerleftmargin-\beamerrightmargin\relax}{3pt}}% 180mm = 250mm - 10mm - 60mm
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If a sidebar is used by the theme, some other horizontal lengths will have to be taken into account: `\beamer@leftsidebar`, `\beamer@rightsidebar` store
the (horizontal) sizes of the side bars, and `\beamer@leftmargin`,  `\beamer@rightmargin`store the distance between sidebar and text.

As **jfbu** has noticed in [`his comment`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179291/how-to-use-margins-in-calculations#comment414136_179296) it is not mandatory to define two new length registers and one could do

```
\def\beamerleftmargin{\dimexpr\Gm@lmargin\relax}
\def\beamerrightmargin{\dimexpr\Gm@rmargin\relax}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Exactly what I was hoping for!

Comment: @jfbu Thanks for the comment. I know that it was not strictly necessary to define the new length registers, but doing so, simplifies the writing of calculations (as you've observed), so I decided to define the lengths. Perhaps I should change the redaction so it's clear that it's not required to define them. I'll add some remark about this.

Comment: your way is to be preferred I agree. However if the macros were changing, one could not use once and for all `\setlength`, on the other hand one could do with a `\def\mymacro{\th@priv@tem@cr@w@thm@ny@@@s}`.

Comment: @jfbu I've added a remark at the end of my answer (using almost *verbatim*) your comment. Thanks.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I will suppress my comment now that it has become team work `;-)`! an alternative having the advantages in terms of syntax of your method with lengths is `\def\beamerleftmargin{\dimexpr\Gm@lmargin\relax}`. It allows situations where the initial thing could change, and we want the current value (without having to bother with `\makeatletter` etc). I should have formulated this way from the start!

Comment: @jfbu No, please leave it; it's really useful (and I've linked it in my answer).

Comment: @jfbu Ah, too late!

Comment: argh... I already suppressed it!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina apologies for suppressing my earlier comment you linked too. The only extra thing compared to your text was to say that inside `\dimexpr..\relax` one is allowed to use any expandable macro. For example with `\def\A{12}\def\B{3pt}` then `\dimexpr\A\B\relax` can correctly be used to specify `123pt` where `TeX` expects a dimension (or inside another `\dimexpr .. \relax`)

Comment: @jfbu No worries! I edited my answer and used instead other of your comments (please, don't delete it, as it's now linked to in my answer ;) ) since it gives a better option.